# To install a 60 amp panel in a shed from my house panel

Tags: electrical-panel

I want to rum 125ft of wire through my attic then go to conduit for 20 ft to mt shed. What size and type wire do I need.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. This is a duplicate of an older question; take a look and see if it gives you what you need.

Comment: The only difference I could see is this is 125' vs 105', and 115' is where I like to start thinking about a size bump on the wire for distance.  You'd have to think about the loads and how close to 60A you actually expect to drive it.  Also think about aluminum wire, #4 is the equivalent of #6Cu at half the price.  Cheaper still if you bump a size.

Comment: Here is another that may give you ideas and it has a nice diagram... : https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/108749/97780